# Bootstrap theme for JSGrid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jsgrid

My application is using Bootstrap and for a certain functionality JSGrid is very adequate, but JSgrid has its own colors and styles. Please let me know if you know of any Bootstrap themed JSGrid css.

Comment: you can add custom css to Bootstrap easily, https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

Comment: Actually, I am looking to style JSGrid rather then Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the styles in the jsGrid-theme.css like this and add it to your own stylesheet after loading the jsGrid stylesheet:

```
.jsgrid-header-row > .jsgrid-header-cell {
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```